# Why does C puts appends a newline while fputs doesn't?

Tags: c, puts, fputs

The C standard provides two functions, [`puts`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/puts.html) and [`fputs`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fputs.html), with `puts(s)` behaving as `fputs(s, stdout)` except that it additionally appends a newline:

> The `puts()` function shall write the string pointed to by `s`, followed by a `<newline>`, to the standard output stream `stdout`.

What is the rationale for this difference in behavior between `puts` and `fputs`?

Comment: Maybe because stdout is line buffered by default and will print when it reaches a newline. More convenient then flushing or adding new line manually.

Comment: It's mostly a question of ”that is the way it was designed in the late 70s”.  There was an analogous discrepancy between `gets()` and `fgets()`.  However, `gets()` is no longer part of standard C, for solid security reasons, so with luck you aren't aware of it, and it is best to stay that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `puts` function specifically writes to `stdout` which is commonly a console.  Because console output is typically line bufered, it's convenient to not have to explicitly add a newline to a string to print.

The `fputs` function can write to any given `FILE` object, not just `stdout`, so by not automatically adding a newline it makes the function more flexible in the general case.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks. I only wish the difference in behavior was reflected in naming.